# sklearn: modify (Standard)Scaler

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to scale a variable to have the mean zero and the Standard deviation 0.5(!). The closest I could find, `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` seems to be non-modifiable - or am I missing something?

Is there another existing scaler for this purpose - or what would be the easiest thing to do here (except for doing it manually ;) )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the mean is 0 and `σ(CX) = Cσ(X)` where C is some constant I'd just multiply after.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X = pd.Series(range(100)).to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)  

X1 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

X1.mean()
#4.440892098500626e-18  i.e. 0
X1.std()
#1.0
```

With 1/2 standard deviation:

```
X1 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)*0.5

X1.mean()
#2.220446049250313e-18  i.e. 0
X1.std()
#0.5
```